# Banded matrix implies chordal

Tags: graph-theory

Consider an undirected graph $G=(V,E)$ with $n$ vertices and all self-loops included in $E$. How do I prove that banded matrix (corresponding to the vertices) implies chordal graph?

Comment: Strictly speaking, is not any matrix a banded matrix?

Comment: No. A banded matrix must have at least one all-zero (non-principle) diagonal.